# SSH returning value while using EOF

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am using linux bash shell. I want to return value from ssh while using EOF.I am new to this.

```
result=$(ssh -T -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o 
StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ConnectionAttempts=3 ${host_name} << EOF
 echo "Get details in mysql"
EOF  2>/dev/null)
```

This gives error saying

```
unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
```

In my actual usecase i have somany commands to run on remote host and get results. So i will have somany linux commands in between EOF

Comment: Why is there a newline before `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`?

Comment: @ melpomene i could not add it in single line in this website. Please update me if you have the answer. How do we use SSH and EOF to return the results back

Comment: I am using linux bash shell.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending delimiter (`EOF`) must be alone on its line:

```
result=$(ssh -T -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o 
StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=60 -o ConnectionAttempts=3 ${host_name} << EOF
 echo "Get details in mysql"
EOF
2>/dev/null)
```

From [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **Here Documents**
>   This  type of redirection instructs the shell to read
>   input from the current source until a line containing only *delimiter*
>   (with no trailing blanks) is seen.